# Why I can't capture UDP packets sent by my Java application with wireshark?

Tags: java, udp, wireshark

I'm developing an application which is using UDP to communicate, I have a "Listen server" and a "Sender". I can receive packets and print them to the console but I can't capture the packets with wireshark. I need to verify the UDP header and data sent but I can't because I don't capture anything with wireshark.

The Listen Server (receiver) and the Sender is running on the same computer but I'm performing the action (sending packets) on my external IP address (66.55.44.33:1234).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Listen Server (receiver) and the Sender is running on the same computer

Then:

- if you're running on Linux, capture on the interface named "lo";
- if you're running on another UN*X, try capturing on the interface named "lo0";
- if you're running on Windows, you're out of luck.

As EJP noted, your packets are getting looped around internally, so you have to listen on a "loopback" interface, if the OS has one and lets you capture on it.

Comment: Wireshark most definitely can capture on the interfaces in question, just as can tcpdump and other capture programs.  Nothing about Wireshark requires packets to be "on the wire".

Answer (score 1):

Because Wireshark captures packets that have been on the wire. You are using internal loopback, even if you don't think so.